# 90MB heap size when loading drawables

Tags: android, image, memory

I want to show a preview of some images from the users device. For this purpose I search the external storage for image files and for every folder which contains some, I list the folder's name and an image from this folder in a listview.
On my Nexus there are 6 folders containing images, so I have 6 listview items.
I load all images using:

```
Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath())
```

And cache the resulting drawable in a HashMap in order to prevent loading the same image multiple times.

However, the heap is growing from 20MB to >90MB. When the images are loaded the app response is delayed like 2 seconds. Pretty bad.

I have no idea how the heap can grow to 90MB from 6 images which are like 50KB but whatever. To fix this I tried to load subsampled bitmaps from the images - however whenever I load them I get an outofmemory exception.

I have verified multiple times that not more than those 6 images are loaded.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the tool what Egor described and there were no memory leaks. The images took about 30MB heap. This amount can only be reduced by reducing the image size. My solution uses subsampling and takes about 3MB heap now.

```
private Drawable loadDrawable(Context context, File file) {
        Drawable drawable = drawables.get(file);
        if (drawable == null) {
            final int targetSize = 500;

            // get subsampling factor
            Options opts = new Options();
            opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
            int largest = opts.outWidth > opts.outHeight ? opts.outWidth : opts.outHeight;
            float factor = largest / (float) targetSize;
            factor = Math.round(factor);

            // load bitmap with subsampling
            opts = new Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = (int) factor;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            drawables.put(file, drawable);
        }
        return drawable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is analyze your app's memory usage using MAT tool, as described in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) amazing article. This tool will help you identify potential memory leaks and see what exactly triggers the heap growth.